# NPOI create cell containing bold and non bold text

Tags: c#, npoi, cell-formatting

I'm using NPOI to output excel from Asp.Net MVC app and works very well with plain text but have now been requested to add formatting and am having problems where I need to have a single cell with bold text followed by non-bold text. e.g.

> **This text bold** - this text normal

I know I can give a cell a single style but this won't help and I cannot see anyway to give a cell some pre-formatted rich text.

The only possible solution that I can think of is creating two cells separately and the merge them together but will that then mean the formatting will be lost?

Is there a way to do this that I have missed in NPOI?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a fair amount of investigation it seems that you are not able to do this inside of NPOI as it doesn't provide the necessary functionality to allow you to set formatting on specific text within a cell like I was attempting to do.

Comment: False. (You should accept one of the given answers)

Comment: @Slight this was answer nearly 4 years ago. At that point the code didn't work as I needed it too, even with the proposed solutions. As an aside can I ask what the value is in down voting a nearly 4 year old answer?

Comment: @Nathan, could you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6911583/463571 Answer was created in Aug, 2011

Answer (score 31):

Fortunately, you able to do that... Look at this code:

```
Font f1=wb.CreateFont();
f1.Color=HSSFColor.RED.index;
ws.GetRow(1).GetCell(0).RichStringCellValue.ApplyFont(1, 5, f1);
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. Very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 31):

You may try this:

```
        var font = reportWorkbook.CreateFont();
        font.FontHeightInPoints = 11;
        font.FontName = "Calibri";
        font.IsBold = true; 

        var cell = headerRow.CreateCell(0);
        cell.SetCellValue("Test Bold");
        cell.CellStyle = reportWorkbook.CreateCellStyle();
        cell.CellStyle.SetFont(font);
```

Comment: I have used this to set the bold text to the whole cell, not half/half

Comment: OP is asking about rich cell text. How would you apply this font to part of the cell's text?

Comment: The `Boldweight` property is outdated and its function is now replaced by bool property `IsBold`.

Answer (score 7):

Seems that the Ernie Banzon answer no longer works exactly as described, possibly due to a namespace change (or in fact that I'm using the HSSF namespace?)

```
// usings
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;

// IWorkbook doc
IFont font = doc.CreateFont();
font.FontHeightInPoints = 11;
font.FontName = "Arial";
font.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.BOLD;
```

Comment: OP is asking about rich cell text. How would you apply this font to part of the cell's text?

Answer (score 2):

Use this option

```
 font.Boldweight = (short)700;//FontBoldWeight.Bold;
```

Actual syntax should be like below. But both of these syntax doesn't works sometime

```
font.Boldweight = FontBoldWeight.Bold ;  
Or 
font.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.Bold;
```

FontBoldWeight is type enum, which after type casting may not work sometime. As a workaround if you type caste or use actual short value of enum directly,  it works. Below is the declaration of FontBoldWeight. it will make things clear.

```
**public enum FontBoldWeight
    {
              None = 0,
              Normal = 400,
              Bold = 700,
    }**
```